# Remove (or exclude) one function from imported package

Tags: r

Is there a way to exclude a function from an imported package. For example, I use almost all of `dplyr` but recently, they added a new function called `recode` that overwrites a function that I have from a proprietary package (that I can't make changes to).

Is there a way to exclude the s3 function from the namespace so it only sees the function from my package and ignores the one from `dplyr`.

I'm aware that we can import one-off functions from a package with ease, but in this case, I'm looking to exclude - just one.

Comment: If you load the package you want after `dplyr` shouldn't your desired function mask the `dplyr` one?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work because the proprietary package doesn't export it's functions properly.

Comment: I see. So, I was going to suggest just forking dplyr on GitHub and removing the function you don't want, but if you say they recently added it, why not just use the most recent version that didn't have `recode`?

Comment: What about the following: `library(dplyr); recode <- NULL; library(myPackage)`.  does this work, or is there something about functions in the namespace being protected? It appears to work on a test I did, but not sure overall.

Comment: The problem here is that `myPackage` imports `dplyr`.

Comment: @Imo I think that's just the same as loading your package after `dplyr` because if you just do `library(dplyr); recode <- NULL; recode()` R still finds recode in `dplyr`.

Comment: I was honestly unaware there are proprietary R packages. the more you know...

Comment: also, I presume you've contacted the proprietary package owners/maintainers to alert them to this discrepancy?

Comment: @MichaelChirico anything that's not open source is proprietary. aka, code you've done for a company that they don't and won't share = proprietary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

R 3.3.0 or later now support ["import all but x,y,z from foo" statements](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L616-620):

> ```
>   \item The \code{import()} namespace directive now accepts an
>   argument \code{except} which names symbols to exclude from the
>   imports. The \code{except} expression should evaluate to a
>   character vector (after substituting symbols for strings). See
>   Writing R Extensions.
> ```

Methinks that is exactly what you want here, and want most people want who do not intend to have dplyr clobber over functions from the stats package included with R such as `filter` or `lag`.

*Edited based on later discussion in comments*:

Example usage example in file `NAMESPACE` per [Section 1.5.1 of WRE](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) is as follows:

```
import(dplyr, except = c(recode, lag, filter))
```

Comment: this is generally extremely useful but may not be helpful to the OP, who is using a proprietary package whose `Imports:` statements they apparently can't change ... ?

Comment: It is the side effect `Imports:` of `dplyr` he complains about, and has control over. Methinks this is in fact what he is after.  I thought the `cannotTouchProprietaryPackage` is imported whole, as are _parts_ of `dplyr`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel have you seen a usage example documented somewhere?

Comment: Although a usage example would be great. I've tried a bunch of different possibilities but it doesn't seem to be working (R 3.3.1) `import(dplyr, except = recode)` nor `import(dplyr, except = "recode")`. In both the function is still being imported (or at least one of it's S3 relatives).

Comment: [Read the fine manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports): `import(foo, except=c(bar, baz))`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me... did you test this? `import(dplyr, except=c(recode))`

Comment: Not working for me either. I've tried a bunch of different invocations. My proprietary package builds without complaint. But the except doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Sounds like something you may want to take to r-devel or r-package-devel.  As I mentioned, I have not yet used it either but know of its existence.  We need something like this ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel are you referring to the mailing lists?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen yes the mailing list

Comment: This is the best answer, because it's very straighforward to implement. But it doesn't seem to work! Even though I see the documentation for it.

Comment: I second your frustration. I also tried exactly this a few weeks ago, as it was documented, and it didn't seem to work.  Needs a follow-up to r-devel.  Could you do that?

Comment: if you're using `roxygen2` to build your NAMESPACE, you can do this with: `#' @rawNamespace import(dplyr, except = c(recode, lag, filter))`

Comment: I have no problem editing `NAMESPACE` and do not need helpers for that; but I am still (years later!) unsure if this mechanism was ever implemented successfully.  My tests were inconclusive, which may of course be on my end.  But that failure to actually 'import all but those named' is the very gist of the comments preceding yours, and AFAICT still the actual issue here.

Answer (score 10):

The other alternative would be to use

```
recode <- SILLY_PROPRIETARY_PACKAGENAME::recode
```

at the head of your code (with an explanatory comment) to create a copy of `recode` in the global workspace (which should then mask the version from `dplyr`). This could prevent future confusion when you hand your code to someone who has the stock `dplyr`, rather than your personally hacked version, installed.

Comment: I'll upvote it, but it seems to lack the fun and excitement of hacking ;)

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me. Somehow, `recode.numeric` from `dplyr` still gets dispatched before my generic `recode` function in the global environment.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen now we're getting hacky, but you could add `SILLY_PROPRIETARY_PACKAGE:::recode.numeric` like above. maybe use an `eval` call with what you learn from `methods` to automate this if it works

Comment: I take it being proprietary means you can't see the source of `recode`? calling `dplyr`'s `recode` methods implies to me that your package's `recode` is just a call to `useMethod("recode")`

Answer (score 4):

Use the Hack-R version of `dplyr` instead of the Hadley version. Given that I created this in the past 2 minutes, you could also easily make your own version.

```
require(devtools)
install_github("hack-r/dplyr")
require(dplyr)
```

All I did was fork it, open the project in RStudio via version control, remove `recode`, commit, and push it back to my GitHub.

Comment: Sure, but you just create a stale leaf in the grand tree of R packages. This won;t get you updates etc pp.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I know, but what's your point? 1. How long does it take to update? 30 - 60 seconds? 2. Do you really need updates for `dplyr`? Most people I know intentionally freeze the version of the packages they're using in production code (and the problem OP is facing is a good example of why).

Comment: I take the proper functioning of the R, CRAN, BioC, ... ecosystem *very* seriously, as I do for eg Debian and Ubuntu and their over 20k packages.  You are very free to have a different opinion, but that won't stop myself (and others) from thinking you're wrong.  Nothing wrong with "hacking for hackings sake" but I am concerned with proper production systems, as is Brandon for his client.

Comment: I've got to agree with Dirk, although unspecified in my question, the reason I'm not just using the older package is because I don't want backwards dependencies. This would create a situation where I have to update this every time dplyr updates. Solution? Yes! Perfect? No :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `library()` gained this functionality in version 3.6, in the form of the `exclude` and `include.only` parameters.

See https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/03/19/managing-search-path-conflicts/

```r
library(digest, exclude="sha1")
digest(letters)
#> [1] "5cab7c8e9f3d7042d6146f98602c88d2"
sha1(letters)
#> Error in sha1(letters): could not find function "sha1"
```

or:

```r
library(digest, include.only="sha1")
digest(letters)
#> Error in digest(letters): could not find function "digest"
sha1(letters)
#> [1] "005ae317c931561a05b53fcfa860d7ac61dfec85"
```

As compared to how it would appear without either of the options:

```r
library(digest)
digest(letters)
#> [1] "5cab7c8e9f3d7042d6146f98602c88d2"
sha1(letters)
#> [1] "005ae317c931561a05b53fcfa860d7ac61dfec85"
```

Very neat!

<sup>(R.4.0.3 was used for the reprexes above)</sup>